# How to write a subprogram to read from a binary file and write in a text file?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char floare[40];
  char culoare[30];
  float pret;
  int codf;
}FLOARE;


void creare_fisier(char*nume) {
  FILE*g;
  FLOARE f;
  fopen_s(&g, nume, "wb");
  if (!g)
    printf("Eroare");
  else
  {
    printf("Cod floare:"); scanf_s("%d", &f.codf);
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        getchar();
        printf("Nume floare:"); gets(f.floare);
        printf("Culoare floare:"); gets(f.culoare);
        printf("Pret:"); scanf_s("%f", &f.pret);
        fwrite(&f, sizeof(FLOARE), 1, g);
        printf("Cod floare:"); scanf_s("%d", &f.codf);
    }
    fclose(g);
  }
}

void afisare_fisier(char*nume) {
  FILE*h;
  FLOARE f;
  fopen_s(&h, "lista.dat", "rb");
  if (!h)
    printf("Eroare");
  else {
    FILE*g;
    fopen_s(&g, nume, "w");
    fread(&f, sizeof(FLOARE), 1, g);
    while (!feof(h)) {
        fprintf(g, "%d %s %s %f", f.codf, f.floare, f.culoare, f.pret);
        fread(&f, sizeof(FLOARE), 1, g);
    }
    fclose(g), fclose(h);
  }
}

void main() {
  char numef[] = "lista.dat";
  creare_fisier(numef);
  char numetxt[] = "raport.txt";
  afisare_fisier(numetxt);
}
```

The subprogram which creates  the binary file is working, but the listing of the information into a text file is not working. When I run the code it's not happening anything and the space occupied by the text file is growing as I keep open the console. I don't really have experience with the subprograms, but I know the structure of listing into a text file.

This is for a homework task.

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) and [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: The professor from my course always use !feof(file) and the code works always perfectly , also the gets(). I don't think that this is the problem.

Comment: Well prof and you have not looked carefully enough: the last data is likely to be repeated if you don't check (and act on) the return value from `fread`. But in this case you do check `feof` before acting on the read.

Comment: @AndreeaElena even I redirect stdin  (e.g. `./a.out < file`)  feof() is never true in creare_fisier() ... but of course gets does nothing, and raport.txt is just explosing my disk never finishing to grow

Comment: @AndreeaElena Many professors are not real programmers, and they pass on many common errors like this, and we have to fix students like you.

Comment: So instead to ease my work, the professor makes it more difficult :)) yey . That's why I'm really struggling in doing these homeworks :((

Comment: @AndreeaElena: maybe, but don't get into the habit of blaming your educator exclusively. CS courses still need hard work on the part of students (i.e. students should not seek for others to do their work for them).

Comment: Uh, I now see you used `feof` twice. The usage in `creare_fisier()` is incorrect, but the usage in `afisare_fisier()` is like it was intended to be used. Still, you should check the returned status value of the input functions.

Comment: @halfer , thank you for your advices

Comment: @AndreeaElena I added more remarks in my answer since you accepted it, they can interest you, reread my answer

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the  more recent versions of the C language.  I.E. Your compiler should have told you this.  Suggest using `fgets()` instead ( read the MAN page for `fgets()` as the parameters are different than those for `gets()`

Comment: The function: `main()` only has two valid signatures: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Notice that they all have a return type of `int`.  Not `void`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Eroare");`  1) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` 2) when the error is from a C library function should also output (to stderr) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest calling `perror()` as that performs both outputs to `stderr`

Comment: OT: regarding: `fopen_s(&g, nume, "w");`  ALWAYS check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `fread(&f, sizeof(FLOARE), 1, g);
    while (!feof(h)) {
        fprintf(g, "%d %s %s %f", f.codf, f.floare, f.culoare, f.pret);
        fread(&f, sizeof(FLOARE), 1, g);`  Much much better to use the returned value from `fread()` to control the loop, similar to: `    while( fread(&f, sizeof(FLOARE), 1, g) == 1)
    {
        fprintf(g, "%d %s %s %f", f.codf, f.floare, f.culoare, f.pret);
    }`  and since this is outputting a text file, suggest appending a '\n' to the end of the format string  I.E. "%d %s %s %f\n"

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT: the function: `scanf_s()` returns the number of input format specifiers successfully read.  Code should ALWAYS  check that returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: regarding: `typedef struct {
  char floare[40];
  char culoare[30];
  float pret;
  int codf;
}FLOARE;`   1) should always include a 'tag' name because that is what most debuggers use to enable displaying the contents of the individual fields.  2) for flexability (and other reasons) should separate the definition of the struct from a typedef for that struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run the code it's not happening anything and the space occupied by the text file is growing as I keep open the console.

This is because you use *feof* and you mix *gets* and *scanf*

Note you also (try to) read in *g* rather than in *h* in `afisare_fisier`

Here a proposal :

I always use *fgets* to read on *stdin*, first because that allows to indicate the max size to read while *gets* can overflow the received buffer, and to not have to do a *getchar()* or equivalent in the hope to bypass a newline etc.

The newline are part of the read strings so in fields *floare* and *culoare*, probably you have to remove them.

In case *floare* and *culoare* are words and do not contain space(s) you can replace the *fgets* (+ *sscanf*) by *fscanf* to not have the newlines in *floare* and *culoare* (do not forget to indicate the max size when you *fscanf* a string).

Note that using the result of *fgets* to detect EOF (rather than *feof*) I do not have to put it two times in the source.

I added the check all time a file is open

I give the name of the two files in argument to `afisare_fisier` because there is no reason that one knows the name of the input file.

Because *EOF* is not easy from stdin I also stop to read when it is not possible to *sscanf* the *Cod floare*, that allows to terminate on an empty line (the user just hit `<enter>` without digit before)

```
typedef struct {
  char floare[40];
  char culoare[30];
  float pret;
  int codf;
}FLOARE;


void creare_fisier(char*nume) {
  FILE*g;
  FLOARE f;
  fopen_s(&g, nume, "wb");
  if (!g)
    printf("Eroare");
  else
  {
    char s[32];

    for (;;) {
      printf("Cod floare:");
      if ((fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL) ||
          (sscanf(s, "%d", &f.codf) != 1))
        break;
      printf("Nume floare:"); 
      if (fgets(f.floare, sizeof(f.floare), stdin) == NULL)
        break;
      printf("Culoare floare:"); 
      if (fgets(f.culoare, sizeof(f.culoare), stdin) == NULL)
        break;
      printf("Pret:");
      if ((fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL) ||
          (sscanf(s, "%f", &f.pret) != 1))
        break;
      fwrite(&f, sizeof(f), 1, g);
    }
    fclose(g);
  }
}

void afisare_fisier(char * in, char * out) {
  FILE*h;
  FLOARE f;
  fopen_s(&h, in, "rb");
  if (!h)
    printf("Eroare (in)");
  else {
    FILE*g;
    fopen_s(&g, out, "w");
    if (!g)
      printf("Eroare (out)");
    else {
      while (fread(&f, sizeof(f), 1, h) == 1) { /* read in h, not in g */
        fprintf(g, "%d %s %s %f\n", f.codf, f.floare, f.culoare, f.pret);
      }
      fclose(g);
    }
    fclose(h);
  }
}

int main() {
  char numef[] = "lista.dat";
  creare_fisier(numef);
  char numetxt[] = "raport.txt";
  afisare_fisier(numef, numetxt);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Cod floare:123
Nume floare:nume1
Culoare floare:culoare1
Pret:12.34
Cod floare:456
Nume floare:nume2
Culoare floare:culoare2
Pret:21.4
Cod floare:
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat raport.txt
123 nume1
 culoare1
 12.340000
456 nume2
 culoare2
 21.400000
```

Note : I hit `<enter>` when the third *Cod floare* was requested